# What are the consequences of using a t-test in a U-Shaped Distribution?

Tags: t-test

What are the consequences of using a t-test in an heavily U-shaped distribution (in both groups). Does the result tend to underestimate or overestimate the significance?
Is there a good citable study for the consequences?
I am aware that there are better tests for this case, I am interested in evaluating existing results that have used the t-test for group differences in a U-shaped distribution.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what happens in a simulation study that compares two U-shaped beta distributions, say $\text{Beta}(0.1, 0.1)$ and $\text{Beta}(0.1, 0.1) + \Delta\mu$.

Comment: @Dave Why not go all the way and explore the limiting distributions "Beta$(0,0)$"? By taking the limits carefully these are just Bernoulli$(p)$ distributions. As you know, for $p=1/2,$ a t-test works pretty well even in samples as small as $n=5.$ That gives us insight into how U-shaped distributions might affect a t test generally. The bottom line is that we have to worry about skewness and extreme kurtosis, but in cases where the moments are bounded--as in all Beta distributions--and there's little skewness, t tests work very well indeed.

Answer (score 1):

One distribution family that contains U-shaped distributions is
$\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$ with $\alpha, \beta < 1.$ The support
for the beta family is $(0,1),$ so an optimal test to distinguish
one beta population from another with a shifted-beta distribution
would look at maximum and minimum values.

However (as Commented by @Dave), it may be of interest to see what happens when we try to
use a t test to distinguish between a population distributed
$\mathsf{Beta}(.1,.1)$ and population distribution with the same
beta distribution shifted to the right by $0.23.$ Both distribution
have SD about $0.46.$ (So the shift is about half a standard deviation.)

For comparison, we start by using R to approximate the power (about 94%) of a two-sample Welch t test
to distinguish a shift in mean of $0.23$ of *normal* populations with samples of size $n_1 = n_2 = 100.$

```
set.seed(609)
pv.norm = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(100,10,.46), 
                            rnorm(100,10.23,.46))$p.val)
mean(pv.norm <= .05)
[1] 0.94108
```

Then we find the power (about the same) of this test for a roughly analogous situation
for a shift in *beta* populations.

```
set.seed(610)
pv.beta = replicate(10^5, t.test(rbeta(100,.1,.1), 
                            rbeta(100,.1,.1)+.23)$p.val)
mean(pv.beta <= .05)
[1] 0.94528
```

The similarity in powers is hardly a surprise because t tests use means
of samples of size $n$ and, by the Central Limit Theorem, means of large samples
from a beta distribution (even an aggressively bimodal one)
are very nearly normally distributed.

```
set.seed(2020)
a = replicate(10^5, mean(rbeta(100, .1, .1)))
mean(a);  sd(a)
[1] 0.4998844
[1] 0.04569338
hist(a, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2", 
     main="n=100, Means of Beta Samples")
  curve(dnorm(x, mean(a), sd(a)), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

A Shapiro-Wilk test of normality on the first 5000 sample means (as many as the test will accommodate) shows no departure from normal.

```
shapiro.test(a[1:5000])$p.val
[1] 0.3998924
```

Comment: How would Slutsky's theorem play into this?

Comment: It seems more directly relevant to explore optimal tests for distinguishing between sample from beta and shifted beta. For example, what is the probability that all 100 treatment values stay in $(0,1)?$ I get very nearly $0$ for that, which means pwr of optimal test with $n_1=n_2=100$ is nearly 100%.// t test may not be technically inappropriate, but it avoids sufficient statistics and so wastes great gobs of relevant information.

Comment: Perhaps a more relevant alternative hypothesis would be a Beta distribution with the same variance as the null but a shifted mean. For instance, the alternative to a Beta$(0.1,0.1)$ with a shift of $+0.23$ would be a Beta$(0.691, 0.255).$ Generally, when the null is a Beta$(\alpha,\beta),$ a shift of $\epsilon$ gives a Beta$(\alpha^\prime,\beta^\prime)$ where $$\alpha^\prime=\lambda^\prime(\mu+\epsilon),\ \beta^\prime=\lambda^\prime-\alpha^\prime$$ where $\lambda=\alpha+\beta$ and $$\lambda^\prime=(1+\lambda)(\mu+\epsilon)(1-\epsilon-\mu)/(\mu(1-\mu)) - 1.$$